# Неверный подсчет в Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

Запрос осуществляется в 3 разные таблицы по общим двум столбцам: AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY

Count считает некорректно.
В чем ошибка?

```
SELECT
   t.AFFECTED_ITEM,
   t.SUBCATEGORY,
   Table2,
   Table3,
   Table4

FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY FROM [dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY FROM  [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY FROM  [dbo].[REQUESTM1]
) t
LEFT JOIN (select AFFECTED_ITEM, count(*) as Table2 from [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] group by AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY) as t2 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t2.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN (select AFFECTED_ITEM, count(*) as Table3 from [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1] group by AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY) as t3 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t3.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN (select AFFECTED_ITEM, count(*) as Table4 from [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[REQUESTM1] group by AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY) as t4 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t4.AFFECTED_ITEM

WHERE t.AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL AND t.SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Count считает некорректно". А как должно быть корректно?

Comment: Наверное, проблема в том, что в условиях связывания Вы забываете установить соответствие ещё и по `SUBCATEGORY`.

Comment: Union у вас плодит записи, так что вид хороший. Программа считает корректно. 1. Если вам нужно убрать дубли - поставьте distinct. 2. Если у вас проблема  с вложеной таблицей (дубли по count внутреннему) проверяйте условия where вложеного запроса (который относится к даному count). 3. Если вам нужна консолидация полученого результата, обверните ещё в один select сделайте sum(поле с числом) и групировку по 1,2 столбцу.